# How to use LIMIT 25 in @Query in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch 25 records from `employee` table but I am getting error (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`). And I want to sort it by `insertedTimeStamp` below is code

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e where e.name = :name AND e.address = :address order by e.insertedTimeStamp LIMIT 25")
public List<Employee> findByNameAndAddress(@Param("name") String name, @Param("address") String address);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) parameter to your query and change return type to [Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html). It makes the query a bit shorter

```
@Query("from Employee e where e.name = :name AND e.address = :address")
Page<Employee> findByNameAndAddress(@Param("name") String name, @Param("address") String address, Pageable pageable);
```

Usage

```
int pageIndex = 0;  
int pageSize = 25;
String propertyToOrderBy = "insertedTimeStamp";     
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize, Sort.Direction.ASC, propertyToOrderBy);

Page<Employee> page = repository.findByNameAndAddress(name, address, pageable);
List<Employee> list = page.getContent();
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! here insertedTimeStamp data type is Date and this property is available in Employee entity class like private Date insertedTimeStamp; then how shall I sort it.

Comment: `Sort.Direction.ASC` and  `propertyToOrderBy` parameters are used for generating `order by e.insertedTimeStamp` query part

Comment: You can even try to change `Page<Employee>` to `List<Employee>` as repository method return type. As far as know it should work, but I have never used it with a `List`

Comment: If I want to fetch unique object then, how shall we use it.

Comment: This query have to return employees with unique ids

Comment: `group by` statement can be used, but the result would only one employee for each salary. You should provide more info about expected result in new question.